# Syntax highlighting for tags

Tags: discussion

The Sith lord Tim has granted us the usage of syntax highlighting for GD.SE but since this isn’t automatically highlighted, the mods have to assign the language syntax to the tag.  If you see a tag assigned to a question that could use syntax highlighting for GD.SE, suggest it here. Please place each tag suggestion in its own answer so we can mark if we completed or denied your request.

#### Completed

- [css](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/css) → lang-css
- [html](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/html) → lang-html
- [svg](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/svg) → lang-xml
- [javascript](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript) → lang-js
- [indesign-scripting](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indesign-scripting) → lang-js
- [illustrator-scripting](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/illustrator-scripting) → lang-js
- [photoshop-scripting](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photoshop-scripting) → lang-js

Comment: Worth noting that you can explicitly activate specific language highlighting (regardless of tags) by using comment hints above your code (e.g. `<!-- language: lang-js -->`)

Comment: See [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184108/307988)

Comment: InDesign, Illustrator, and Photoshop "support[s] scripts written in AppleScript (on Mac OS), VBScript (on Windows) or JavaScript (on either OS)." Note the multiple languages. On Stack Overflow, each language has a tag on its own in addition to the application.

Comment: @RadLexus I was going to suggest taking the highlighting off the generic scripting tags and having specific language tags but from what I can tell there is no AppleScript highlighting available and I don't remember the last time I saw any VB, so I don't know if it's worth it.

Comment: @Cai applescript highlighting works with the default but the question should be asked what language is being used with the applescript and we should apply that tag for it, ie JavaScript

Comment: Thanks for adding the possibility - [that's so much better](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/76679/30216).  The OP didn't mention XML or XSLT so I added the magic language line manually. Still, a huge improvement.

Comment: Is there some limit to languages? I tried to tag some of my answers `<!-- language: lang-py -->`, `<!-- language: python -->` and `<!-- language: lang-python -->` to no avail. I do have python answers [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/78240/), [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/46867/), [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/61808/), [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/56200/) and [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27300/) to name a few.

Comment: Make an answer and i will work on it tomorrow when I have time

Answer (score 3):

- [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [css](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/css) → lang-css

Answer (score 1):

- [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [inkscape](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inkscape) → lang-xml
- [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [xml](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xml) → lang-xml

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that manually entering a language tag does not seem to work. I have tried to mark my python answers with:

- `<!-- language: lang-py -->`
- `<!-- language: python -->`
- `<!-- language: lang-python -->`

But it did not seem to do anything. Is mannually marking the language not supported?

Some examples of answers in python (mostly mine):

- [Programmatically creating radiating rows of dots](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/56200/programmatically-creating-radiating-rows-of-dots/56207#56207)
- [Data merge for PDF](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/61808/data-merge-for-pdf/61824#61824)
- [Is it possible to revert preapplied alpha blend and find original color?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/78240/is-it-possible-to-revert-preapplied-alpha-blend-and-find-original-color/78250#78250)
- [Faded Colour Code Calculation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/46867/faded-colour-code-calculation/46870#46870)
- [How to create a vector curve programmatically?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/37998/how-to-create-a-vector-curve-programmatically/38010#38010)
- [Export multi page pdf with gimp](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/63491/export-multi-page-pdf-with-gimp) (Look one that is not mine)
- [autoshrink with aspect ratio](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/74504/autoshrink-with-aspect-ratio/74511#74511) (and more)

Comment: Added the tag python

Answer (score 1):

- [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)[batch-processing](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batch-processing) → lang-sh
- [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)[imagemagick](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/imagemagick) → lang-sh

Comment: Why not have all this be in the same answer? :P

Comment: Why does it matter?  Plus i get pinged everytime someone leaves an answer.